# I want to change from a developer to tester. I am getting 8LPA. If I change Will I get a higer pay than this?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, java

I want to change from a developer to tester. I am getting 8LPA. If I change Will I get a higer pay than this ? I have 5 yrs of experience .

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-much-does-one-get-inhand-from-Adobes-8lpa-CTC

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that better to move in SDET [Software Developer Engineer in Test]. Because you have good development experience try learn manual testing and automation testing with any tool (Selenium, Appium etc.). By this skill set you can expect more.

"By the way this is not the right forum to ask these type question".